# UK Post doc salary and National Insurance scheme for an expat

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom, salary

I've been offered a post doc position in the UK and I'm trying to understand how the whole package works so I can make an informed decision before I accept or reject.

Say for example, I've been quoted a salary of £34,377 in line with the [national average](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salaries/postdoctoral-researcher-salary-SRCH_KO0,23.htm).
What would be the total amount I get for a year accounting for tax and any other standard things that a foreign national might not know about? I've heard about National Insurance, but I don't know how that factors into a quoted salary offer. And practically, how much would I have deposited into my bank account per week?

Also, I'm not intending to stay in the UK permanently. What would happen to the NI after I leave? Does it get paid out when I leave the country?

Comment: Most UK employers operate under the PAYE scheme (pay as you earn) which means NI contributions and income tax (both scaled according to your pay -- you can google the amount) are deducted automatically from your salary before it gets paid to you. The only tax you will have to pay yourself is council tax, which depends on where you live and the size of your house (it pays for the upkeep of roads, drains, rubbish collection etc). When you move in, you will get a letter from the council with your band and how to pay (usually monthly or annual direct debit).

Comment: The only thing to note is that you may be placed on an "emergency" tax code to begin with, and so may pay more tax on your first payslip than is correct. In my experience, this is usually corrected after the first month and the extra tax automatically refunded to you. More info on all of this here: https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/articles/tax-and-national-insurance-deductions